# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' for percentage encoding

Tags: python

i want to encode the variable string by percentage. I confuse coz the last time i use this code and it's worked :

data type :

```
df_train.info()
```

output :
[image]

**Percentage encoding**

input :

```
freq_oc = df_train['Occupation'].value_counts().reset_index()
freq_oc.rename(columns={'index':'Occupation','Occupation':'freq_Occupation'},inplace=True)

freq_oc['pct_Occupation']=round((freq_oc['freq_Occupation']/freq_oc['freq_Occupation'].sum())*100,2)
freq_oc
```

output :
[image]

i use this dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/parisrohan/credit-score-classification

and i dont know why but currently shown an error : [image]
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'**

I tried the solution below to use int but showing another error :
[image]

i really confused since i just run and restart the kernel without changing any code / dataset but the error is showing up. What cause this ? is it because the new version of python ?

please suggest, thanks

Comment: Please put the error message into the question as text, not an image.

Comment: And what is `df_train`?  Your code doesn't include an import statement, and you don't mention it in the text.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: Please include the dtypes of your dataframe. It appears that freq_Occupation is a str. But its best to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `dtype` to `int` of `freq_Occupation`(it was `str`ing as mentioned in error), before performing division, like this

```
freq_oc['freq_Occupation'] = freq_oc['freq_Occupation'].astype(int)
freq_oc['pct_Occupation']=round((freq_oc['freq_Occupation']/freq_oc['freq_Occupation'].sum())*100,2)
```

Comment: now an error is : TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: @AmeliaPutriDamayanti Show full traceback by updating your post. The error is from some other different line of code.

Comment: @AmeliaPutriDamayanti, you are not using my answer. Copy paste my two lines as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `freq_oc['freq_Occupation']` is `str`. Change to numerical using `pd.to_numerics()` before performing the division, or cast using `int(freq_oc['freq_Occupation'])` if these are just integers.

Comment: Its a dataframe. int(freq_oc['freq_Occupation']) isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Change the operands for `/` to `int` type:**

Change:

```
freq_oc['pct_Occupation']=round((freq_oc['freq_Occupation']/freq_oc['freq_Occupation'].sum())*100,2)
```

To:

```
freq_oc['pct_Occupation']=round(int(freq_oc['freq_Occupation'])/int(freq_oc['freq_Occupation'].sum())*100,2) # Note the conversion to int type.
```

Comment: Its a dataframe. `int(freq_oc['freq_Occupation'])` isn't going to work.

Comment: thanks, but the error still persist :(

Answer (score 0):

convert to float

```
freq_oc['freq_Occupation'] = freq_oc['freq_Occupation'].apply(lambda k:float(k))
```

Comment: `.astype` would be more appropriate than `.apply`